# How do to get asset history in hyperledger composer using the asset id?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have an asset that I have created in hyperledger composer and I want to get the transaction history of the asset using the asset id.

one of the work around as suggested in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372302/how-do-i-find-the-history-of-transactions-for-an-asset-in-a-blockchain-implement) is to  emit an event to every transaction that makes changes to the asset and then query the historian record based on the events emitted.

This is what I mean

```
// transaction that is going to make changes to the asset
transaction ModifyAsset{
 o String assetId
}

// event
event ModifyAssetEvent {
 o Asset asset
 o String assetId
}

// queries  the historian record
query searchProductHistory {
  description: "search product by serial number"
  statement: 
    SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord
    WHERE (eventsEmitted[0].assetId == $assetId)
}
```

This is could have been ideal but unfortunately Hyperledger composer cannot allow such a query.

Any other solution that I can use to achieve my goal will be highly appreciated

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you make a query to return only transactions with the specific asset id works.

Something like:

```
let q1 = businessNetworkConnection.buildQuery(
'SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord'
 + 'WHERE (transactionId == assetId)'
);
```

Comment: the transaction ids are different from the asset ids and therefore it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, but maybe something like

transaction.transactionInvoked.eventsemitted.asset == assetName

maybe Works.

Comment: unfortunately Hyperledger composer seems not to allow such type of queries, otherwise thank you.